# UWP C# Pasar date picker a otro

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

Soy algo nuevo en UWP y quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de pasar la información de un Date Picker a otro nuevo, lo que tengo en XAML es

```
<StackPanel Name = "ContenedorElementos">
    <CalendarDatePicker Name="FechaEntr" Margin="0,0,30,0" PlaceholderText="Fecha entrega" />

    <Button Content="Agregar" Width="100" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

En C# tengo lo siguiente

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StackPanel nuevoItem = new StackPanel();

        nuevoItem.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        nuevoItem.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        nuevoItem.Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,30);
        nuevoItem.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

        nuevoItem.Children.Add(
            new DatePicker
            {
                //Aquí quiero pasar la información de "FechaEntr" al nuevo DatePicker
            );
        ContenedorElementos.Children.Add(nuevoItem); //El StackPanel al que va entrar el nuevo StackPanel con el DatePicker
    }
```

Existe alguna manera de colocar la información de "FechaEntr" al nuevo DatePicker?

Edito, solucioné ocupando el código de abajo, parece que solo debemos almacenar los valores en una variable implícita y de ahí mandarlos al constructor de un nuevo DateTime.

```
var valoresFechEntr = FechaEntr.Date; 
nuevoItem.Children.Add( 
new DatePicker 
{ 
  Date = new DateTime(valoresFechEntr.Value.Day, valoresFechEntr.Value.Month, valoresFechEntr.Value.Year) 
});
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Si tienes que añadir información puedes [edit] la pregunta. Borra el comentario y para cualquier añadido hazlo de esa forma. Es recomendable conseguir la medalla [Informado](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed) que es tan sencilla de ganar como leer el [Recorrido completo](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender cómo funciona el sitio.

Comment: pero alli noto que creas un datapicker nuevo y lo agregas a la ventana, no es solo la asignacion de la fecha sino generar controles dinamicos desde codigo

Comment: Si, en efecto pero lo que buscaba era almacenar los valores para asi poder pasarlos al nuevo DatePicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que pasa si simplemente usas

```
var valoresFechEntr = FechaEntr.Date.Value; 

nuevoItem.Children.Add(new DatePicker { Date = valoresFechEntr });
```

en este caso asignas directo el DateTime de a fecha de entrega al date el picker que creas dinamico por codigo

Comment: Mas practico de lo que pensaba, funciona a la perfeccion, muchas gracias.